# PHP : Doesn't upload image

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit-post"])){
    $desc = $_POST['description'];
    if (strpos($desc, "'") !== false) {
        $desc = str_replace("'", "_", $desc);
    }
    $sql_home = "INSERT INTO home (description) VALUES ('$desc');";
    if($conn->query($sql_home) === TRUE){ echo "<br>Great!<br>"; }
    else{ echo("<br>Nope!<br> "); }
    $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/imgs/home/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded. <br>";
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack! <br>";
        echo "$uploadfile <br>";
    }
    echo '<br>Here is some more debugging info: ';
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "<br>";
    error_reporting(-1); ini_set("display_errors", true); //?
}

?>
```

Every time I try to upload an image ( .jpg ) it says "**Possible file upload attack!**". Help.
Gives me two warnings:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/imgs/home/calcetto.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/admin/db/manage.php on line 199
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpGvLsAC' to '/var/www/html/imgs/home/calcetto.jpg' in /var/www/html/admin/db/manage.php on line 199
```

*Please note:*

1. I tried both absolute and relative paths;
2. php.ini: file_uploads = On
3. I copied and pasted the code from php.net
4. this file is `/var/www/html/admin/db/manage.php`
5. images to upload are here: `/var/www/html/imgs/home`

Here is the html:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name='description' placeholder='Image description'></textarea><br>
    <input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit-post' value='Upload'></input>
</form>
```

Comment: write  `error_reporting(-1); ini_set("display_errors", true);` just after php start you will get the error.

Comment: check if directory has permission to write

Comment: "uploaddir" is at right place as you defined ?

Comment: You should really check the upload path.

Comment: @TarangP yes, it is.

Comment: @Prateik Darji yes, it has

Comment: Pleas show Full PHP code. like includeing if(isset ) ..

Comment: can u please update question with location of your php file url from where you are uploading image and directory path.

Comment: Updated @TarangP

Comment: Done @PrateikDarji

Comment: and what about the url from which url are you tring to upload the image

Comment: @PrateikDarji i'm uploding the image from /var/www/html/admin/db/manage.php (here are both the form and the php code)

Comment: so in url the path is http://localhost/project/admin/db/manage.php right

Comment: @PrateikDarji should be localhost/admin/db/manage.php, (the root is /var/www/html, the site index is /var/www/html/index.php)

Comment: ok and that error_reporting should be on the top  please make that changes and let me know if you find any error or not

Comment: @PrateikDarji now two warnings appear, i'm updating the question in a minute

Comment: How is that possible? .-. from ftp works

Comment: change `imgs` and `home` both directory permission with 777

Comment: @PrateikDarji thank you very much! Now it works! :D

Comment: so is it permission issue let me know i will write answer so it can help others?

Comment: @PrateikDarji Yes, I solved adding permission 777 (cmd: chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/imgs and chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/imgs/home) (I kept move_uploaded_file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing my answer from comments.

Please check for the errors by PHP error reporting

just write

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", true);
```

you need to check for permission to the upload directory,
if you have subdirectory then you need to have write permission on both of the directories

you can change the permission by the following commands `-R` will update the permissions for subdirectories as well

```
chmod -R 777 uploaddirectory
```